# How can I select those values efficiently?

Tags: sql, next.js, mysql2

the user will provide some filters to get articles from database that need to be filtered out at same time. For example "get up to 10 articles with tag foo or baa, more than 10 likes and contains the text 'hello' in title or content itself" so I write below sql query. My question is: a stament like

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE 
    JSON_CONTAINS(tags, JSON_ARRAY('foo')) OR
    JSON_CONTAINS(tags, JSON_ARRAY('baa'))
```

will read all the results, right? but only up to 10 is needed. Same pattern goes to all `select` statements I'll concat, so far 3 but it may be up to 5, as I add more filters. In the end of sql query I do use a `LIMIT` but this only I read *all* records from each articles, right? can I optimize that? or shouldn't worry about that? What i'm worrying about is how I get alot of articles, it'll use alot of memory and increase the response time to return the articles.
The goal is show up to 10 records, this meant to be used in search result, then do some pagination  so say I got total 33 items, page 1 I read 1-10, page 2 11-20, page 3 21-30, page 4 31-33 etc. Current sql query goes like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE 
        JSON_CONTAINS(tags, JSON_ARRAY('foo')) OR
        JSON_CONTAINS(tags, JSON_ARRAY('baa'))
    
    UNION

    SELECT * FROM articles WHERE 
        contents LIKE '%hello%' OR
        title LIKE '%hello%'
            
    UNION

    SELECT * FROM articles WHERE 
        count_likes >= 10
    
) AS combined_result
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

if matters, I'm using nextjs and mysql2 module. Is there a better way to do this? How is that usually done? I'm totally open to new ways to do that.
Thanks in advance